# Calling a client-side function that is inside of a UserControl from the Page level in ASP.NET Webforms

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms, user-controls

I have an ASP.NET UserControl sitting inside of an ASP.NET Page.

The ASP.NET UserControl has the following logic in it which works correctly:

**Button in UserControl:**

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbCalculate" Text="Calculate" OnClientClick="SaveGridData(); return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**Here is the client-side function that is called: (also in UserControl)**

```
function SaveGridData(sender, args) {
    var grid = $find('<%=grid1.ClientID%>');
        grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
    }
```

The client-side function ends up going into a grid event on the server called grid1_BatchEditCommand which saves all of the data in the grid (also in UserControl).

---

The above works perfect when the Calculate button which resides within the UserControl is clicked. However, I need to also run the same exact logic when a button on the Page that the UserControl resides in is clicked.

I started out by trying to expose a public function inside the user control called SaveGrid() which has a RegisterStartUpScript that calls SaveGridData(). Then on btnFromParentPage_OnClick event I call SaveGrid(). No luck.

```
public void SaveGrid()
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "test", "SaveGridData();", true);
}
```

**In Parent Page code behind:**

```
protected void btnFromParentPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    userControl1.SaveGrid();
}
```

**I also tried the following as a last resort:**
`<asp:Button ID="btnOnParentPage" runat="server" SkinID="Success" Text="Save & Close" OnClick="btnOnParentPage_Click" OnClientClick="SaveGridData(); return false;" />`

The JavaScript function is called and it works, however now I can't access the OnClick server-side event of this button now because of the return false line and without the return false line the JavaScript function doesn't get called... There is a lot more logic that still needs to run.

Comment: Could it be that the script generated by `RegisterStartupScript` is getting executed before the `SaveGridData()` function is available? Does that function reside in some separately loaded .js file? I'd be curious to see what the generated script looks like and what if any console errors appear in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply navigate up or down a control tree to find the control and get it's `ClientID`.

```
var grid = $find('<%= userControl1.FindControl("grid1").ClientID %>');
```

For this to work the User Control has to be defined on the aspx page and not added dynamically from code behind. If it is added from code behind then you have to get the ClientID programatically also and put it on the page as a string.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript functions and variables are all public (unless you enclose them), so your `SaveGridData()` function is already accessible to the entire page without any additional code. Your other button on the page can easily access it using the same code you used for the Calculate button:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnFromParentPage" Text="Save & Close"
 OnClientClick="SaveGridData(); return false;"></asp:LinkButton>
```

**EDIT:** If you want to run the server code after the JavaScript function, simply remove the `return false`:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnFromParentPage" Text="Save & Close"
 OnClientClick="SaveGridData();"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: I actually tried this too. Please see the bottom of my post (I just updated it). This works as far as calling SaveGridData(), but now because of the return false I can't get into the actual server-side OnClick event that this button has.

Comment: Basically my question now is: How do I run this buttons server-side logic also in the server-side OnClick event?

Comment: Then remove the `return false` from the button on the page (and keep it for the Calculate button). See my edit.

Comment: it turns out that my problem is that this line in SaveGridData(): grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView()); is not calling the grid's server-side batcheditcommand event probably because the button click is interfering.. Any ideas? I think 2 postbacks are being fired.

Comment: It's really hard to imagine what you're trying to achieve. Yes, removing `return false` to make the button post back to the server will interrupt the grid's code. Why do you want to do so many things with one button? In that case stick with JavaScript. Put back the `return false` and then make the button call a JavaScript function that will call `SaveGridData` and then post back when `saveChanges` is finished. Now the issue becomes **How to detect when `saveChanges` is finished?**

Answer (score 0):

Sorry if I mislead people with my question, but the primary issue was related to the fact that the line:

```
grid.get_batchEditingManager().saveChanges(grid.get_masterTableView());
```

In SaveGridData() calls a server-side event of the grid control on the page. This does not work well when you are also trying to go into a button click server-side event at the same time.

**The solution:**
Expose an event at the end of of the UserControl grid1_BatchEditCommand server-side event function in the UserControl. Then from the parent page tap into this event. The additional logic of the button on the parent page that needed to be ran, now just runs inside of the event rather than btnOnParentPage_Click.

**Here is the flow:**

1. btnOnParentPage is clicked which only calls the client-side function
   SaveGridData() in the UserControl.
2. This makes a call to run the grid1_BatchEditCommand event on the
   server (it works because there is no other server-side event being
   called at the same time)
3. Then at the bottom of the BatchEditCommand code is the new Event
   that I exposed. The code on the parent page that is inside of this
   event (that I initially had in btnOnParentPage_Click) now runs.